# python Ensure necessary functions are imported with dependent functions

Tags: python, module

I have a python module I am writing with some generally useful functions that I import individually.  However, some of these functions will require helper functions that are shared between them.  Rather than copying the helper function into each main function that is dependent on it, is there a way I can ensure that the helper function is always imported with its dependent functions.

for example I have function A  which generates an array for functions B,C, and D.

For example if I had a module named 
Useful_functions which had:

```
def a(n):
    return n*5

def b(n):
     return a(n)
```

in my script where I use the functions I could just do

```
 from useful_functions import A,B
```

however I am looking for something like an `include a` statement that will ensure that if B,C, or D is ever imported then A will also be imported automatically.

Comment: There is no vanilla support for this in Python, as far as I know. I don't really understand why it would be necessary. Generally, automatically doing stuff is not the Python way. Explicit is better than implicit....

Comment: You only need to import those things that you will be invoking.  If you want function `A`, but it depends on function `B`, you only need `from functions import A`.

Comment: `from useful_functions import *`?

Comment: Wow, Patrick Haugh is right.  Python automatically includes functions that are referenced... This is why I love python.

Comment: @jeffpkamp OH so you meant in `my_module_with_B` you already import and use `A` from `useful_functions`? Yeah, no need to re-import that.  Note, when you `import useful_functions` *everything* in that module gets executed, including it's own import statements.